# How to renew expired DRM license in Cast Receiver Player?

Tags: javascript, google-cast, drm, google-cast-sdk, widevine

I develop custom Cast Receiver application based on [Google Cast Application Framework](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/) The receiver app is responsible for playback Widevine encrypted streams. Our backed solution requires to add **DRM token** to `PreAuthorization` header in license request. I need to perform a couple of authorized requests to retrieve the **DRM token**. I assumed that the best place to retrieve DRM token is to use [Message Interceptor](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/advanced):

```
this.playerManager_.setMessageInterceptor(
cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, (loadRequestData) => {
  var media = loadRequestData.media;
  var customData = media.customData;
  var licenseUrl = customData.licenseUrl || null;
  var contentId = media.contentId;
  var cdn = customData.cdn || null;
  return this.getOriginMediaURL(contentId, cdn, PlayerApiImp)
  .then(playbackURL => {
    loadRequestData.media.contentId = playbackURL;
    loadRequestData.media.customData.contentUrl = contentId;
    return this.getDRMToken(customData);
  })
  .then(drmToken => {
    this.preAuthToken = drmToken
    this.playbackConfig_.licenseUrl = licenseUrl;
    return loadRequestData
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.log_({'ERROR': error});
    return loadRequestData;
  });;
});
```

Then CAST Player automatically calls `licenseRequestHandler` and I easily add required DRM token to the headers of license request:

```
this.playbackConfig_.licenseRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
  if (this.preAuthToken) {
    requestInfo.headers = {};
    requestInfo.headers['PreAuthorization'] = this.preAuthToken;
  }
};
```

**Playback works fine but until the time when license key has expired**. On our backend license lives ~30min. After that time the receiver player generates error `[cast.framework.media.ShakaPlayer] category: 6 code: 6014` and playback stops.
I found that [this error means](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/blob/76f78187b6533c4fdabb505451f603313b1d474d/lib/util/error.js)
[image]

So my questions are:

1. Does Cast Receiver API support license renewing? What callbacks in CAST API does receiver trigger to notify that session has expired? I don't receive any, I only get error :( and playback stops.
2. How I can provide new license to the player to prevent it from failing?

Comment: Are you not getting new calls to licenseRequestHandler when the license should be renewed? By that time your preAuthToken might have expired though.

Comment: @colde I investigated and saw that receiver player doesn't call new 'licenseRequestHandler'. I'm really don't know how to renew license

Answer (score 0):

We've achieved this by using the manifestHandler method of the PlaybackConfig. It can return a Promise, so we've been able to detect whether the token could be expired or not, and renew it accordingly.

```
castContext
  .getPlayerManager()
  .setMediaPlaybackInfoHandler(
    (loadRequestData, playbackConfig) => {
      playbackConfig.manifestHandler = manifest =>
        retrieveUpfrontToken(loadRequestData)
          .then(token => {
            playbackConfig.licenseRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
              requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
              requestInfo.headers['x-dt-auth-token'] = token;
            };
          })
          .then(() => manifest);
    };
  );
```

The manifestHandler method is called each time the Receiver is fetching the manifest (after each ad breaks or at each update period for a dynamic manifest).

I hope I've been helpful, this is quite complicated to get some help/answers from Google...

Best,
Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

Read the properties of the license and see if it is renewable. If this property is not set to true you cant renew the license.