# Using a custom CAF Google Cast receiver, how can I perform an async operation before each DRM license request?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, drm, receiver, caf

Using a Google Cast V3/CAF receiver, I would like to perform a network request before each DRM license request and include some of the resulting info (entitlement info) in the license request, as a header.

The Cast framework provides [`PlaybackConfig.licenseRequestHandler`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.PlaybackConfig#licenseRequestHandler) which allows you to modify a license request before it is made, but it doesn't allow you to perform an async operation before the request - i.e. you can't return a Javascript Promise from `licenseRequestHandler`.

[This answer is doing something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401570/24245), but that won't work for live streams since that solution resets `licenseRequestHandler` each time the manifest is loaded, and the manifest is loaded continuously during live streaming. I want to perform this pre-license async operation before license requests **only**, not every time the manifest is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, currently. This has been submitted to Google as a feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/155215189